# How to remove scientific exponent of a number?

Tags: typescript

Typescript is giving `TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

```js
let [ , num ] = hiResNum.toString().match(/^([+-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*)(e[+-]?[0-9]+)?$/);
num = parseFloat(num).toFixed(digits);
```

> let num: any Type 'RegExpMatchArray | null' must have a
> 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)

How should I separate the scientific notation part of a number?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `String.match` function can return `Array | null` and `null` isn't iterable. So, you need to know that `r` is null or not; then you can use `r[1]`.

```
const r = hiResNum.toString().match(/^([+-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*)(e[+-]?[0-9]+)?$/);
if (r && r.length > 1) {
    num = parseFloat(r[1]).toFixed(digits);
}
```